# Best way to check 2 spaces above, below, left , right of point in 2D array?

Tags: c#, arrays, 2d

I have a 5x5 2D array in C#.  I need to check the 2 spaces above, below, right and left of the array. What is the best way to do this?  The try catch statements are for when it has to check a point that would be out of bounds.

This is what I have so far, and it *works*, but it just looks sloppy.

```
bool[,] boardSpaces = new bool[5, 5] { 
    { true, true, true, true, true }, 
    { true, true, true, true, true },
    { true, true, true, true, true },
    { true, true, true, true, true },
    { true, true, true, true, true } 
};


for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
    {
        if (boardSpaces[x, y] == false)
        {
            try
            {
                if (boardSpaces[x - 1, y] == true && boardSpaces[x - 2, y] == true)
                {
                    validMoveRemaining = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch { }

            try
            {
                if (boardSpaces[x + 1, y] == true && boardSpaces[x + 2, y] == true)
                {
                    validMoveRemaining = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch { }
            try
            {
                if (boardSpaces[x, y - 1] == true && boardSpaces[x, y - 2] == true)
                {
                    validMoveRemaining = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch { }
            try
            {
                if (boardSpaces[x, y + 1] == true && boardSpaces[x, y + 2] == true)
                {
                    validMoveRemaining = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch { }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "best". Best for what? Getting a passing grade? Minimum amount of code? Most LOC? Efficiency?

Comment: you want to know if a point x,y in your 5x5 matrix is inside the matrix by two positions. right?

Comment: Passing grade isn't a problem. It works properly. Best as in best practice in general. Readability, efficiency, etc.  Also, the catch statement will be modified to only catch out of bounds...soon

Comment: Hooray for [pokemon exception handling](http://www.daimi.au.dk/~andos/images/catchemall.jpg)!

Comment: @vulkanino  No. I'm writing a console Pegz game. I need to check that the point specified has at least ONE set of 2 filled(true) points next to it in any direction.

Comment: @BrandonSee this was unclear in the original question.

Comment: catch is for exceptional handling. Wanting to look a couple of positions away from points at the edges of your array will be an ordinary occurrence. So you should handle those cases before the array reference that would throw an exception in your current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of exception handling, use arithmetic bounds checking. You already have the row and column index as well as the dimensions of the matrix. Why don't you simply if() that?

```
if(x - 2 >= 0 && x + 2 < matrixWidth)
{
  //...
}
if(y - 2 >= 0 && y + 2 < matrixHeight)
{
  //...
}
```

You can even make a compound boolean expression out of it:

```
validMoveRemaining =
  !board[x,y] && (
    (x >= 2 && board[x - 1, y] && board[x - 2, y]) ||
    (x < boardWidth - 2 && board[x + 1, y] && board[x + 2, y]) ||
    (y >= 2 && board[x, y - 1] && board[x, y - 2]) ||
    (y < boardHeight - 2 && board[x, y + 1] && board[x, y + 2])
  );
```

There you go! :)

Comment: Thank you. Very concise and easy to read code. A big improvement from what I initially constructed

Answer (score 0):

that's pretty much it. You will definitely need 2 "fors".
You could increase performance by adding some more checks, for example, you don't need to select left on columns 1 and 2 because there aren't 2 left positions so you would check only right. Same logic works for rows, so on row [1,1] you would only check right and bellow. This way you can remove your try catch.

Also you have to check if, since its such a small matrix, maybe the extra check would make it slower than to full loop.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT as per more clear specs.**

```
public bool CanMove(int x, int y)
{
    if ( checkBeforeX(x, y) )
        return true;

    if ( checkAfterX(x, y) )
        return true;

    if ( checkBeforeY(x, y) )
        return true;

    if ( checkAfterY(x, y) )
        return true;

    return false;
}

private bool checkBeforeX(int x, int y)
{
    return x>=2 ? boardSpaces[x-1, y] && boardSpaces[x-2, y] : false;
}

private bool checkAfterX(int x, int y)
{
    return x<=2 ? boardSpaces[x+1, y] && boardSpaces[x+2, y] : false;
}

private bool checkBeforeY(int x, int y)
{
    return y>=2 ? boardSpaces[x, y-1] && boardSpaces[x, y-2] : false;
}

private bool checkAfterY(int x, int y)
{
    return y<=2 ? boardSpaces[x, y+1] && boardSpaces[x, y+2] : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

best way for performance than add borders to array

```
  bool[,] boardSpaces = new bool[9, 9] {  
    { false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false },  
    { false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false },  
    { false, false, true, true, true, true, true, false, false },  
    { false, false, true, true, true, true, true, false, false  }, 
    { false, false, true, true, true, true, true, false, false  }, 
    { false, false, true, true, true, true, true, false, false  }, 
    { false, false, true, true, true, true, true, false, false  },  
    { false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false },  
    { false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false },  
  };

  const int left = 2;
  const int right = left + 5;
  const int top = 2;
  const int bottom = top + 5;

  for (int x = left; x < right; x++)
  {
    for (int y = top; y < bottom; y++)
    {
      ..
    }
  }
```

best way for readability than add directions

```
  var directions = new[] 
  {
     new { dx = -1, dy = 0 }, 
     new { dx = +1, dy = 0 }, 
     new { dx = 0, dy = -1 }, 
     new { dx = 0, dy = +1 } 
  };

  for (int x = left; x < right; x++)
  {
    for (int y = top; y < bottom; y++)
    {
      foreach (var direction in directions)
      {
        if (boardSpaces[x + direction.dx, y + direction.dy] 
           && boardSpaces[x + 2 * direction.dx, y + 2 * direction.dy])
        {
          validMoveRemaining = true;
          break;
        } 

      }
      //..
    }
  }
```